# Excel - combining SUMPRODUCT

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel sheet that I am using to update player ratings.

| Player | Placing | IniRating | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | FinRating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2.0 | 1.000 | 0.018 | 0.016 | 0.014 | 2.007 |
| D | 2 | -2.0 | 54.598 | 0.982 | 0.856 | 0.775 | -1.758 |
| C | 3 | -0.1 | 8.166 | 0.147 | 0.128 | 0.116 | -0.213 |
| B | 4 | 0.1 | 6.686 | 0.120 | 0.105 | 0.095 | -0.036 |

The formulas in cells D2 to G5 is

```
=EXP(-$C2)/SUMPRODUCT(--($B$2:$B$5<=D$1)*(EXP(-$C$2:$C$5)))
```

and the formulas in column H (FinRating) is

```
=((SUMPRODUCT(($D$1:$G$1>=B2)*$D2:$G2)-1)*0.15)+C2
```

I want to apply these formulas across multiple sheets (events) and increase the number of Players (which would require adding more columns) so would be ideal to have them combined in one formula.

Ideally the formula would go into column `FinRating` I could adjust the ranges it referenced and the FinRating would be calculated. Final table would look like this

| Player | Placing | IniRating | FinRating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2.0 | 2.007 |
| D | 2 | -2.0 | -1.758 |
| C | 3 | -0.1 | -0.213 |
| B | 4 | 0.1 | -0.036 |

I've spent some time trying to combine these formulas with no luck, and my exprience using `SUMPRODUCT` is a little light.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Comment: *I want to apply these formulas across multiple sheets and tables* Sorry to ask this but what is the problem? You got 2 formulas that work as expected. Applying these into several sheets takes, literally, seconds (unless you got several sheets). What is the point of resuming these 2 formulas in 1? Anyways, to combine them use IF. Something like `IF header = Finrating then do formula2 else do formula 1`

Comment: I would like ideally to not have the columns marked 1-4 above and instead have all the calculations occur in the one formula. I want to use this formula across alot more players (100+) and many events (100+) so creating these columns across this many events would be too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses 3 helper columns (which could be hidden). Note that you don't need to add more helper columns for a larger number of players --- 3 columns works for all cases.

In `D2` (1st helper column):

```
=EXP(-C2)
```

and fill down.

In `E2` (2nd helper column):

```
=1/SUMIF($B$2:$B$5,"<="&B2,$D$2:$D$5)
```

and fill down.

In `F2` (3rd helper column):

```
=SUMIF($B$2:$B$5,">="&B2,$E$2:$E$5)
```

and fill down.

And finally in `G2` (the final rating):

```
=(D2*F2-1)*0.15+C2
```

and fill down.

I would recommend putting the data in a table and using table formulas. The advantage of this is you don't need to edit formulas when the last row changes (in your example the last rows are all marked with `$5`).

The formulas are pretty much the same, except column names take the place of A1-style references.

In helper column 1, which I've named `Calc1`:

```
=EXP(-[@IniRating])
```

In helper column 2, which I've named `Calc2`:

```
=1/SUMIF([Placing],"<="&[@Placing],[Calc1])
```

In helper column 3, which I've named `Calc3`:

```
=SUMIF([Placing],">="&[@Placing],[Calc2])
```

And in the `FinRating` column:

```
=([@Calc1]*[@Calc3]-1)*0.15+[@IniRating]
```

Comment: This is great, I can probably make this work. Thanks @xidgel

Comment: Optimising further, replace `D2` with `{=1/(SUM(IF($B$2:$B$5<=B2,EXP(-$C$2:$C$5))))}` and `E2` with `=(EXP(-C2)*(SUMIF($B$2:$B$5,">="&B2,$D$2:$D$5))-1)*0.15+C2`